# ReSharper Unit Test Covarage not showing coverage

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, code-coverage, resharper

When running ReSharper Unit Test Coverage in Visual Studio 2019 v.16.11.10 with ReSharper v.2021.3.3, the coverage on the files is not shown/run.

On the image, a snippet of the Unit Test Coverage is shown, where it is seen that the unit tests are run and how much of those tests are covered. Unfolding one of the packages that should be tested by the tests, it is possible to see that ReSharper cannot generate coverage. Is this because all the functionality is packed into the (1.0.0.0, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2)?

If this is the problem, is there any workaround? Or how do I get rid of the line if it causes any problems? If I then get rid of the line, will everything then be packaged in a different manner? Or will everything work the same as before?

[image]

One of the other projects in my team does not have this extra line where everything is packed into, and ReSharper can generate Unit Test Coverage as it should.

Comment: I have a similar issue.  Running "Cover unit tests" twice seems to restore the missing coverage information.

Comment: After a lengthy email correspondence with JetBrains's support, it seems like the problem is with dotCover grabbing the DLL files from the GAC instead, resulting in mismatched ids for the PBDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lengthy email correspondence with JetBrains's support, it seems like the problem is with dotCover grabbing the DLL files from the GAC instead, resulting in mismatched ids for the PBDs.